# Dimension of local operators stabilizing the code space?

Tags: error-correction, mathematics

What is the maximum dimension of a connected group of local operators stabilizing an $ [[n,k,d]] $ code with $ d \geq 2 $?

Some background:

Consider an $ [[n,k,d]] $ quantum error correcting code with $ d \geq 2 $.

A unitary $ V $ on the whole physical $ n $ qubit Hilbert is a logical unitary if the the image of any code state under $ V $ is some other code state.

A unitary $ V $ on the whole physical $ n $ qubit Hilbert space is called a local unitary if it is of the form
$$
V=\bigotimes_{i=1}^n g_i
$$
where each $ g_i $ is a $ 2 \times 2 $ unitary matrix. In other words if it is an element of the group of local unitaries
$$
\bigotimes_{i=1}^n U_2
$$

The proof of the Eastin-Knill theorem considers the group of all transversal logical operators, which is denoted there by $ \mathcal{G} $. It turns out that the $ d \geq 2 $ condition of the code is enough to imply that the entire identity component of $ \mathcal{G} $, which is denoted there by $ \mathcal{C} $, actually stabilizes every codeword, at least up to a global phase. From there the proof concludes by observing that $ \mathcal{G} $ is compact so has finitely many components, and, since the identity component stabilizes the code, each connected component corresponds to a single logical operation. So only finitely many logical gates can be implemented transversally.

However it is not the conclusion of the proof I am interested in. I was just wondering, out of curiosity, how big can this group $ \mathcal{C} $ be? In other words, the question I'm asking is:

What is the maximum dimension of a connected group of local operators stabilizing an $ [[n,k,d]] $ code with $ d \geq 2 $? It can be at least dimension $ 1 $ because of the global scalar.